# CSS circle not rendering at all from S3

Tags: html, css, svg, graphics, amazon-s3

I have recently created a circle in CSS. It sits inline with some text. 
Here is the code:

```
#circle {
        float: left;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        border-radius: 125px;
        border: 3px solid;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 10px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
```

And the corresponding HTML looks like this...

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

This works well and turns out with what I want when I'm simply opening the HTML file in my browser, however as soon as I put the html and css into S3 the circle disappears. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUEZs.jpg) I know that S3 sees the code because when I add an image as a background to the circle it shows the missing image icon.

I also tried both a javascript and SVG circle. For both of these I could not get them to sit inline with the text and floating them had no effect. I'm not getting any errors in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be when in the index you call the css file in link href, tried adding or removing (/) href="/" in the beginning or add the css directly in the head.

Comment: I don't think that is the issue since all my other css works and is coming from the same file. But I may be mistaken.

Comment: can you add a plunker or codepen? the issue is only in S3?